# submitting form then showing loading image by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am submitting a form and loading loading gif in the same div by replacing html of form by html of loading image.

I am first submitting the form then loading gif, because I have to replace the content of div(in which form exist) with loading image.

Logs 1,2,3 are printing, loading image is showing but form is not submitting
Please help.

```
<script>
/* javascriptfunction */

Submit_and_loadimage() {


console.log("1");

document.getElementById("form_in_div").submit(); 

 or   

document.forms['form_name'].submit();


console.log("2");
document.getElementById("form_in_div").innerHTML ='LOADING_IMAGE-DIV';

console.log("3");
```

}

Comment: i dont want to use ajax .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let suppose on button click you  are calling ajax method

```
<button onclick="LoadData();"/>
```

> before ajax call show image and onComplete ajax method hide
>   this image

```
function LoadData(){
    $("#loading-image").show();
    $.ajax({
          url: yourURL,
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
            $("Your div id").append(html);
          },
          complete: function(){
            $("#loading-image").hide();
          }
        });
}
```

Comment: thnx for ur reply... but i cant use ajax , i can only use JavaScript

Comment: then try this
Add div and make it hide by Default.

~<div id="loading">
  <img id="loading-image" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>~

And in java script on page load show that div containg loading image

~<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(window).load(function() {
     $('#loading').hide();
  });
</script>~

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do this easily with plain javascript. When you post a form, the form inputs are sent to the server and your page is refreshed - the data is handled on the server side. That is, the submit() function doesn't actually return anything, it just sends the form data to the server.

If you really wanted to show this kind of working image Javascript (without the page refreshing), then you'll need to use AJAX, and when you start talking about using AJAX, you'll need to use a library. [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) is by far the most popular, and my personal favourite. There's a great plugin for jQuery called Form which will do exactly what it sounds like you want.

Here's how you'd use jQuery and that plugin:

Show your image on form submit

```
$('#myForm')
    .ajaxForm({
        url : 'myscript.php', // or whatever
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function (response) {
           // hide your image
        }
    })
;
```

Comment: ok ... by this logic my form should submit but loading image should not be visible . but it is opposite , why?

Comment: and i just want to show loading image in previous page until next page (after doning some processing of 1-2 min) is loaded.

Comment: @user3869979 Show your image on form submit and your hide image code will go in success section

Comment: @user3869979 if you move on new page simpel rediret user on new page when you get success  by using this window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

Comment: thnx for ur reply , i think the solution u are telling is in case of i will use ajax , ... can u tell me solution if i only use only JavaScript .

Comment: @user3869979 i can't not enplane how it done with plain JavaScript but i have an idea for you . look 1st put the show image code b4 you JavaScript for submission code . then redirect page by server and throw response via URL and if you want to do something with this response then pick this response on page lode . i hop you got the idea what i am saying

Comment: yes this can be a way but problem with this is div (which contain form) is replaced by div (showing image) so form is not available to submit , if i show image first

Comment: @user3869979 simple just use 2 div and use show hide by changing style tags by using java script see this for idea http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can submit your form using ajax so that page won't redirect.
put your loading '.gif' image somewhere in a hidden block

```
<div style="display:none" class="loading">
    <img src="path/to/loading.gif" />
</div>
```

set the display of this div to inline-block when you click the submit button. Then make an ajax call. and hide this div again when yo get response from the server.

with jquery you can do it like

```
jQuery('#submitbtn').click(function(){
    jQuery('.loading').show();
    jQuery.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
      .done(function( data ) {
        alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
        jQuery('.loading').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: thnx for ur reply... but i cant use ajax , i can only use JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

> then try this Add div and make it hide by Default.

```
<div id="loading">
  <img id="loading-image" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />     </div>
```

> And in java script on page load show that div containg loading image

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(window).load(function() {
     $('#loading').hide();
  });
</script>~
```